# Android TabLayout selected tab background

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-tablayout

Is there really really no easy way to use a TabLayout and be able to set the colors of the tabs (selected, not selected)? Like the selected tab background uses `colorPrimary`, non selected tabs uses `colorPrimaryDark` or something? I've searched the web including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611885/changing-the-background-color-of-a-tab-in-tablayout-android-design-support-libr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color) and much more. I can change the background color with solution 1 but now **the indicator is missing and I want it back.**

This can't be so hard to do..

[image: missing indicator]

Solution of first link:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_background</item>
</style>

// tab_background
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

**ANSWER:**

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_background</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

style change

```
  <style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
      <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_background</item>
      <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#000000</item> 
      <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">5dp</item>      
  </style>
```

Comment: how does this answer NOT hide the indicator?

Comment: app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
               app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"

Comment: i think you got me wrong, i want the indicator to be available and displayed not hidden!

Comment: <style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
         <item   name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_background</item><item name="tabIndicatorColor">#000000</item> <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">5dp</item>
 </style>

Comment: my god finally thanks, simple, easy.. I feel stupid now for even asking

Comment: Is it possible to have a custom background like the above and keep the ripple effect as well? (on tap ripple)

Comment: this code is not working for custom tab view while for default tablayout its working fine

Comment: This approach have the downside that applies to all the TabLayouts in your application. In some cases you really don't want that, so the approach to use a <selector> and set is as the tabLayout background could be preferable