# How to set background color only one tab on tablayout?

Tags: android, tabs, background-color, android-tablayout

How to set background color only in one tab of tablayout, like instagram on the first version.

Comment: You can refer this link: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611885/changing-the-background-color-of-a-tab-in-tablayout-android-design-support-libr)