# Tab layout tab does not change background color

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

Please help. Have already tried all existing solutions but it does not work. 
There is the part of the code

```
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2)?.customView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
```

Comment: In the past we've always needed to use a drawable background, and use a `selector` in order to change the background color.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32613364/4409409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `customView()` use `getCsutomView()`. Code should be like:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(2)?.getCustomView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
```

This should fix your problem.